# ReactJS - How can I implement pagination for react with keep state when route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app, I use react-router v.4 and I use pagination from Jason.
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google

Everything is working fine but, when I change the route and then change the route back, the pagination changes the current page back to page 1.

How can I keep the page state when route change?

Comment: Just my 2 cents - Can't you store the page state in the router *container* and pass that state to the route component?

Comment: Hi Sung Kim, do you have any example git applications? Maybe I could learn from those examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With react router, there are multiple ways to handle this:  The props from the Router pass down to you component, you can use a param:

`<Route path="/items/:page" component={Component} />`

and /items/1, /items/2 and use

`props.match.params.page`

Based on a quick view at the example, here:

`this.setPage(this.props.match.params.page || this.props.initialPage)`

And to change the url, in the onChangePage or even in the onClick handler, use something like 
`` this.props.history.push(`/items/${page}` `` . 
You could also use the location.pathname prop and parse the string, or use `item?page=1` and parse location.search, etc.

If you want to maintain state globally and not from the router, you could use Redux.

Comment: That's a winner! 